# Webpack "Refused to apply style from leaflet.css"

Tags: angular, webpack, leaflet

I am using ngX-Rocket angular 8 starter. I want to include this leaflet map library into my project: https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet

I included the file in my index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css" />
```

I am getting the following error in the console:

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:4200/node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

I noticed that there is no webpack.config.js file, so I created one and put:

```
module.exports = {
    "module" : {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.css$/, loaders: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ] }

        ]    
    }
};
```

I also put in my angular.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/workspace/workspace-schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "myproject": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "styleext": "scss"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/apple-touch-icon.png",
              "src/robots.txt",
              "src/manifest.json",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/main.scss",
              "node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ],
              "serviceWorker": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "ci": {
              "progress": false
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "hmr": true,
            "hmrWarning": false,
            "browserTarget": "myproject:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "hmr": false,
              "browserTarget": "myproject:build:production"
            },
            "ci": {
              "progress": false
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "myproject:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "scripts": [],
            "styles": [
              "src/main.scss",
              "node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/apple-touch-icon.png",
              "src/robots.txt",
              "src/manifest.json",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "ci": {
              "progress": false,
              "watch": false
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "myproject-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "myproject:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "myproject"
}
```

Though I am still seeing the error in the web console. What is it do I have to do to get rid of this error?

I included the file in my index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add it in the angular.json file in the `styles` section

```
"styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css"
],
```

You can find more info here: [Adding CSS and JavaScript to an Angular CLI Project](https://medium.com/@davembush/adding-css-and-javascript-to-an-angular-cli-project-2b843a8283f3)

Comment: I am configured to use scss and have updated my OP to include the angular.json file, though it still doesn't work. Can you please check to see if there is something else I need to do?

Comment: Actually I cloned the ngX-Rocket angular 8 starter and added the "./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css" as a style and got it working. Not sure what is the problem in your case. Did you stop the server and build it again after adding the style tag? it should be in the build section